How do I show the function is identically zero
I have been trying to solve the following problem:
Let f be a differentiable function s.t $f:]a,b[\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$.
We suppose there exists a $k>0$ s.t
$$||Df(x)||\leq k ||f(x)||, \forall{x\in]a,b[}$$
Show that if $f$ is zero for some $x_0\in]a,b[$, then $f$ is identically zero.
Ideas: I have been trying to show it for $n=1$ (supposing the function is not identically zero) and it is rather easy to see that the slope at $x_0$ is zero. My track was to try and use the fact that in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, the function uses a $k>1$ where as in other region it may not but this seems like a rather weak argument. In the hints they mention that one should show the following is open:
$$E=\{x\in]a,b[ | f(x)=0\}$$
Any hints would be greatly appreciated, (for $n$ in general).

The hint to show that $E$ is open is to use a topological argument. Namely as $E$ is also closed (w.r.t. subspace topology) therefore if one were to show that $E$ is open, it would be a clopen set in a connected space.
A clopen set in a connected space can only be empty or the whole space $(a,b)$, but by assumption $E$ is nonempty.

Please could you give an additional hint as to show $E$ is open ?

The argument given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349761/if-f0-0-and-fx-leq-fx-for-all-x-in-mathbbr-then-f-equiv-0 can be adapted to your question (where they had $k$=1).

Although now looking back at this question, I wonder if it would be the most straightforward to invoke gronwall's inequality.
